# Разрешить копирование на сайте Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

Здравствуйте, как разрешить выделение мышкой и копирование контента на сайте под Wordpress, никаких плагинов для защиты не ставил, стоит только Yoast seo, все файлы перерыл не нашел ничего что могло бы запрещать выделение текста (наверное плохо искал), может можно как-то сделать принудительное разрешение на выделение текста?

Comment: Чтобы сказать как разрешить копирование, надо знать что его запрещает. Попробуйте поочередно отключать плагины и следите за изменениями.

Comment: И тему еще смените на стандартную и посмотрите

Comment: https://devaka.ru/articles/zashita-kontenta

Comment: Как тема называется?  Или может вы копи-пастом добавили код который это делает?

Comment: отключил плагин который в принципе отвечает за весь вывод информации помогло, а в плагине там файл стилей и пара скриптов в которых я ничего не нашел что могло бы препятствовать этому

Comment: А вы по ссылке - то, что я дал, почитайте

Comment: @KAGGDesign да смотрел первые 2 способа у меня такого нету, прописал эти же 2 способа только с обратным эффектом тоже не помогло

Comment: всем спасибо вопрос решился, у меня подключалась сторонняя библиотека и в ней тоже были стили и скрипты, а в стилях автор библиотеки прописал *{user-select: none;}

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам мешают стили. Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по тексту на сайте и выберите "Исследовать код страницы" или "Inspect". Если у вас в инспекторе вместо абзаца либо текста стал активный какой-нибудь блок, значит он и перекрывает текст. Попробуйте временно поставить этому блоку display: none либо отредактируйте так, чтобы он не перекрывал текст.